# Find the nearest number greater than a specific value among cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 different cells like this in my Excel table:

```
[B1] = 2
[N50] = 5
[V25] = 10
```

I want to find in those cells the nearest number greater than a specific value. For example, if the value is `1` then the number should be `2` in cell `[B1]`. If the value is `4` then the number should be `5` in cell `[N50]`.

Comment: some example data would be of great assist.  This site is a great [tool for posting data from a spreadsheet](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html).  Not so good with blank cells, but if you put a * or a - in the blank cells as a temporary hold it workds great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(A2<LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),1),
  IF(A2<LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),2),
  IF(A2<LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),3),
LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),3),
LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),2)),
LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),1)),
"larger or equal to all searched numbers")
```

and in one nice straight line for copy and paste purposes:

```
=IF(A2<LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),1),  IF(A2<LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),2),  IF(A2<LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),3), LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),3), LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),2)), LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1),1)), "larger or equal to all searched numbers")
```

The hardest part for me and I did not understand it and still do not...just accepting, is building your separate cells into an array.  That part is done by the CHOOSE():

```
CHOOSE({1,2,3},D2,F3,H1)
```

Once it is in an array, perform a large function to sort it from largest to smallest.  Then through a series of nested IF statements, checked to see if the specified number in A2 was smaller than the K largest number.

Here is a proof of concept scaled down to smaller range but give you the idea.

[image: Proof of Concept]

Now I did it with a large, you could have done it with a small function as well, you would just need to alter your logic in the if statements.

This is an alternative approach without the if statements:

```
=IF(A2>=MAX(A7,C8,E6),"Greater than or equal to all options",INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2,3},A7,C8,E6),IFERROR(MATCH(A2,CHOOSE({1,2,3},A7,C8,E6),1)+1,1)))
```

Comment: I have tried both formulas and they work great. Thank you very much Ed, your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: I am not a fan of the IF statement method because its repetitive and kind of fixed for 3 comparisons.  The last formula, takes a different approach and works for as many cells as you build out the array to be.  Its also shorter so I prefer it.  If you do not do the max check at the start, the formula would return the greatest value in the list.